# When are the specializations available?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I'm playing Dragon Age: Inquisition for a while now and I was wondering when I can get the other classes.

I'm a level 9 mage at the moment, so it's possibly a little early but I looked who can make you a rift mage/knight enchanter etc but I don't know when or how I can trigger the class events.

Or do I have to have a specific amount of inquisition points or power?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be level 10, get to a certain point in the main story and then perform a specific quest to be able to gain a specialization like Knight Enchanter, Rift Mage or Necromancer.

Your current level is too low, and you might not have progressed far enough in the main story.

The main quest you have to finish is "In Your Heart Shall Burn", which results in:

> Unlocking Skyhold. There you'll be able to perform a mission on the war table to recruit trainers once you're level 10. Speak to the trainers and perform the quest for the specialization you want to use

Comment: Ah i got this quest on my map so i just habd to wait thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be level 10 to begin specialization for the inquisitor. Just get to skyhold, then once you're able to get to the war table the mission should be available.